# Using JQuery to toggle div visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing some jquery code to toggle a Div visibility.  I followed the method posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ga7Jv/.

When the user clicks an image (next to a H2 tag) i want it to toggle the div.

Here is the Jquery:

```
$(function()
{
$(".expander").live('click', function(){
        $(this).next("#TableData").slideDown();
        $(this).removeClass('expander');
        $(this).addClass('expanded');
});

$(".expanded").live('click', function(){
        $(this).next("#TableData").slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('expanded');
        $(this).addClass('expander');
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<h3><img src="toggle.png" class ="expander" alt="Expand"/> 
Tabular Data</h3>
<div id="TableData">
//Content
</div>
```

The is css applied to the class expander and when i click the button it appears that the css changes, as i would expect.  So i assume the code is finding the toggle button and switching out the classes alright.

However it doesn't perform the action i need, which is to slide the div up or down depending on that class.

The other way i've tried to achieve this is with this:

```
  $(function(){
     $('.expander').live('click',function(){
     $('#TableData').show();
     $('#TableData').hide();
        });
```

This only closes the div and does not open again when i click it.  I've also had it so it closes fine but when i open it, it immediately closes again.

Thanks

Comment: **Side Note:** *As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().*

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, i ended up using Satpal's to avoid changing the class if i didn't need to.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Problem with your code is that its last function call is `.hide()`, thus it will always hide the div

Simply use [**.toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), it display or hide the matched elements.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.expander').on('click', function() {
    $('#TableData').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3><img src="toggle.png" class="expander" alt="Expand" />
</h3>

<div id="TableData">The Core Knowledge Sequence UK is a guideline of the fundamental skills and content to cover in English, maths, history and geography, science, music and visual arts.</div>
<p class="traversing"></p>
```

***OR***

```
$(function () {
    $('.expander').on('click', function () {
        $('#TableData').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

You can use [**.slideToggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/), if you want to display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion

```js
$(function() {
  $('.expander').on('click', function() {
    $('#TableData').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3><img src="toggle.png" class="expander" alt="Expand" />
</h3>

<div id="TableData">The Core Knowledge Sequence UK is a guideline of the fundamental skills and content to cover in English, maths, history and geography, science, music and visual arts.</div>
<p class="traversing"></p>
```

Comment: 'Visibility' and 'Display' are different in CSS `display: none;` and `visibility: hidden;`. jQuery's toggle (and slideToggle) change the display to none, removing it from the page layout - if you want the element to be 'invisible' but still take up the space it previously occupied you need to set `$('#TableData').css("visibility", "hidden");` and then change it back when required.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to switch class names in the same element, better to have one another fixed class in it and keep changing the other ones.

here is what I am saying:

```
$(function(){
    $(".toggler").on("click", function(){
        $(this)
        .toggleClass("expander expanded")
        .parent().next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**TIP:**

- Here `.toggler` is the **fixed class** for the trigger element and I am switching `.expander` and `.expanded` classes in it.
- Also, you are selecting wrong element for slideToggle. #TableData is `.parent().next()`.

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/nuw2M/1/) : http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/nuw2M/1/

Answer (score 2):

Inside your function it shows the div and then hide it again.

You can alternate its state by calling `.toggle()` function, so jQuery decides to show or to hide it by itself.

Answer (score 2):

This fiddle demonstrate how to toggle a div inside the div.

[Toggle div inside the div](https://jsfiddle.net/2q42693m/13/)

`$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.showMe').slideToggle('slow');
});`