# Convert CSS :active to Javascript .onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

I would like to convert `:active` css to `onclick` from Javascript.
The idea is simple enough, I would like to click over `glyphicon` and displays the content.

If I can display the content inside a window popup, it will be magical !

This is my html part :

```
<td class="col-md-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-blackboard cover-icon"></span>
    <div class="coverPDF">
        {% if document.format == 'pdf' %}
           // some things with html + javascript
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</td>
```

And the CSS part :

```
div.coverPDF {
    display: none;
}

span.cover-icon:active + div.coverPDF {
    display: block;
}
```

Through this way, when I click on my glyphicon, it displays content until I unclick this one.

How I can just click one time and show/hide content ? In a window popup ?

Maybe with something like this ?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cover-icon").click(function(){
        $(".coverPDF").hide();
    });
    $(".cover-icon").click(function(){
        $(".coverPDF").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you done any research into "popups"? There are several thousands of articles on the internet about doing that. Otherwise, this question is a duplicate of [Using JQuery to toggle div visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21584623)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JQuery to toggle div visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584623/using-jquery-to-toggle-div-visibility)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use JS(Jquery) instead of CSS.

```
$(".cover-icon").click(()=>{ $(".coverPDF").fadeToggle(300);}
```

Could you try this and let me know!

Comment: $('.cover-icon').on('click', '.coverPDF', function() {
$(".coverPDF")..toggle();})