# jquery how to only have 1 active toggle at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a website that requires me to have 18 icons of which, each icon has its own assign div that is hidden, and once pressed the hidden Div slides down  and shows below the icon. These icons have to be in a different Div from the content I want to hide/show.

I'm using Elementor on wordpress since I'm really ignorant when it comes to webdesign and programing,

I've found this jquery that I'm using to show and hide Div when I click on icons.
I've assign the icons as .showBlock1 .ShowBlock2 .ShowBlock3 etc and the Divs as .hiddenBlock1 .hiddenBlock2 .hiddenBlock3 etc... and it works how I want except that I only want 1 active at a time, so that if I press icon1, it shows Div1 and then if I press icon2, it hides Div1 and shows Div2 and so on.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    
  var hbtn = $(".showBlock");
  var hcon = $(".hiddenBlock");
  
   hcon.hide();
   hbtn.click(function(e) {
   var index = hbtn.index(this) 
   $(hcon).eq(index).slideToggle("slow");

   e.preventDefault();     
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    
  var hbtn = $(".showBlock2");
  var hcon = $(".hiddenBlock2");
  
   hcon.hide();
   hbtn.click(function(e) {
   var index = hbtn.index(this) 
   $(hcon).eq(index).slideToggle("slow");

   e.preventDefault();     
    });
});
```

Since I'm really ignorant to coding I've been just repeating the script and changing the numbers on the class .showBlock and .hiddenBlock.

Comment: You don't need so much of code to toggle on click you can check [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584623/using-jquery-to-toggle-div-visibility#21584680) there is also a [codepen link](https://codepen.io/peternguyen/pen/KfyIo)

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm really new to this and I'm really struggling. I've tried using the reference and it's not working (my fault no doubt).
What I need is to click a button and make a div on a different part of the page to hide/show and I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: No issues with it this is helpers community and hope this is solved ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question to clarify for example  what "1" means...

Comment: I have edited the question, I'm really sorry, in my head it seemed clear.
Hope it's understandable now.

Comment: Hello, being ignorant you cant fix this, first prepare your mind, definitely following answer will fix it, Good Luck !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following is helpful to you?

```js
$(function(){
  var hbtn = $(".showBlock");
  var hcon = $(".hiddenBlock");
  
  hcon.hide();
   hbtn.click(function(e) {
     var curr=hcon.eq(hbtn.index(this)); 
     hcon.not(curr).hide(); 
     curr.slideToggle("slow");
     e.preventDefault();     
    });
});
```

```css
.cont1 {height:50px}
.hiddenBlock {display: inline-block; width:60px; height: 40px; background-color:#ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cont1">
 <div class="hiddenBlock">1</div>
 <div class="hiddenBlock">2</div>
 <div class="hiddenBlock">3</div>
 <div class="hiddenBlock">4</div>
 <div class="hiddenBlock">5</div>
 <div class="hiddenBlock">6</div>
</div>
<div>
 <button class="showBlock">show 1</button>
 <button class="showBlock">show 2</button>
 <button class="showBlock">show 3</button>
 <button class="showBlock">show 4</button>
 <button class="showBlock">show 5</button>
 <button class="showBlock">show 6</button>
</div>
```

A button click will at first hide all visile `.hcon` elements and will then `.slideToggle` the one corresponding to the button position.

**Edit**

After having had a look at your web page I can simplify your structure as shown below:

```js
jQuery(function($){
 const btns=$("div.showBlock");
 const scts=$("section.hiddenBlock");
 $("section").on("click","div.showBlock",function(){
  let curr=scts.eq(btns.index(this));
  scts.not(curr).hide();
  curr.toggle();
 });
})
```

```css
.showBlock   {display: inline-block; background-color:#ccc; 
              width:50px; margin:2px;padding:6px}
.hiddenBlock {background-color:#eea; width:192px; padding:6px; margin-top:8px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
<section
  class="... elementor-element-51eaf85 ..." data-id="51eaf85" data-element_type="section">
  <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no">
    <div class="elementor-column ... elementor-element-1a773d0 showBlock" ...>
      one
    </div>
    <div class="elementor-column ... elementor-element-6b9441a showBlock" ...>
      two
    </div>
    <div class="elementor-column ... elementor-element-ce4f2d4 showBlock" ...>
      three
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="... elementor-element-fc98ed1 hiddenBlock ..." data-id="fc98ed1" style="">first section</section>
<section class="... elementor-element-cf64eb5 hiddenBlock ..." data-id="cf64eb5" style="display: none;">second section</section>
<section class="... elementor-element-f16da07 hiddenBlock ..." data-id="f16da07" style="display: none;">third section</section>
...
```

The HTML structure there is an excerpt from the page. I removed a few class attributes to improve the readability and added a little makeshift CSS to make it "presentable".

On top of that I unified your classes "showBlock1", "showBlock2", "showBlock3" to "showBlock" and "hiddenBlock", "hiddenBlock2", "hiddenBlock3" to "hiddenBlock".

Have a look at it and play around with it ...

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me, since I'm really bad at this, I don't know how to identify my 18 icons, (which are all scattered through different parts of the page.) to my 18 other Div (which are all scattered through different parts of the page.).

Comment: It would help if you could provide your HTML too as my example above was obviously only a very rudimentary one.

Comment: Since I made the website with elementor, which is a webdesigning tool it's hard for me to provide the html, however here's the website page https://uniway.chitas.cloud/protecao/ maybe it can help getting my point across. I'd really appreciate the help and thank you so much for everything.